# How to append to menu items selectively

Tags: theme-development, menus

I'm making this wordpress theme, and I need to create a menu that is vertical but its submenus are horizontal, like this:

```
MenuItem
 SubmenuItem | SubmenuItem 
AnotherMenuItem
 SubmenuItem | SubmenuItem
```

Now using wp_nav_menu() and CSS I can get this effect, but I don't have any idea on how to add the pipe symbol to separate the submenu items.

```
wp_nav_menu(array(
            'container'=>false,
            'after'=> ' | ',
            'theme_location'=>'home-menu',
            'menu_id'=>'main_nav_left',
            'menu_class'=>'main_link',
        ));
```

is no good as it will turn out as

```
MenuItem |
 SubmenuItem | SubmenuItem |
```

(adding a | after every item, which is the documented behavior)
I was wondering if there was a way to selectively add the pipe symbol so that it is added only between the submenuitems and not after anything else. 
According to WP documentation, there doesn't seem to be a built-in method to support this.

So what is the best way to accomplish this effect (without editing wp core code)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is another case where a pure-CSS definition will work. For example:

```
#main_nav_left li:after {
    content: ' | ';
}
#main_nav_left li:last-child:after {
    content: '';
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I never knew CSS could edit content. How cross-browser-friendly is this though?

Comment: Browser support is [actually pretty good](http://css-tricks.com/9189-browser-support-pseudo-elements/) for the `:before` and `:after` pseudo-elements.

Comment: I see, I'm using it now and it works like a charm!